# calloc implementaion in tlsf assertion failed

Tags: c, embedded, heap-memory, calloc

after executing the below function on an embedded system *(esp32)*, the assertion in heap_tlsf.c fails, my code is:

```
remained_data = (char *)calloc(lbws - where_to_insert + 2, sizeof(char));
```

the `lbws - where_to_insert + 2` evaluates around `1100`, this call will panic and gives the below assertion error:

```
assert failed: insert_free_block heap_tlsf.c:239 (current && "free list cannot have a null entry")
```

I can't figure out what is the meaning of this assertion, and what is the cause for it, so as the solution for it.

so what should I do to fix this? thank you.

Comment: did you check if remained_data is different from NULL? It faild before or after the calloc()?

Comment: Hard to say with the little info given... but my guess is that some of your other code that you didn't post has an error.

Comment: You most likely corrupted some memory beforehand in some other part of your code; this could be anywhere in your code.

Comment: From the TLSF doco: "Nevertheless, we assume that TLSF will be used in a trusted environment, where applications are written by well intended programmers. Therefore, initialising the memory is a useless feature that introduces a considerable overhead."... I suggest switching to `malloc()` and see if the problem goes away... Sounds like `calloc()` isn't their jam...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Well-intended (intending?) programmers wouldn't be using that lib in the first place. [Why should I not use dynamic memory allocation in embedded systems?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/286121)

Comment: @Lundin the SDK (esp-idf) used this library,  so this is not our choice and as my test shows, i can allocate 1000 byte using **calloc** or **malloc**, but the preceding parts will panic with the same error, on the other hand we did allocate much more space without any problem, because there is around 130 KB space left on the heap, idk for now, but thank you and i will consider your comment.